# How can I get StyleSheet css rules using webcomponent.js

Tags: javascript, web-component

I'm coding a web component recently, and now try to add webcomponentsjs polyfills for other unsupported browser, but I have a problem when I'm using it.

I have to get a childNodes stylesheet css rules for dynamic changes, the code here works fine in chrome:

```
        node = this['root'].childNodes;
        //this['root']: is <template> element
        //Here is webcomponentjs console.log in Firefox:
        //Object
        // { __impl4cf1e782hg__: <template#sd>,
        //          parentNode_: undefined, firstChild_: undefined, 
        //          lastChild_: undefined, nextSibling_: undefined, 
        //          previousSibling_: undefined, treeScope_: Object }

        style = node[1]['sheet'].cssRules;

        if(bgColor || hairColor){
            for(i = 0; i < style.length; i++){
                if(style[i].selectorText === '.base'){
                    style[i].style.background = bgColor;
                }
                if(style[i].selectorText === '.hair'
                   || style[i].selectorText === '.hair::before'
                   || style[i].selectorText === '.hair::after' ){
                    style[i].style.background = hairColor;
                }
           }
        }
```

The problem is I can't access `node[1]['sheet'].cssRules` in webcomponentsjs in firefox and safari, since it's inside one more layer `Object { __impl4cf1e782hg__: <template> ... }` , although I get inside to it `['__impl4cf1e782hg__']` , but I'm not allow to get anything. How to change this code for webcomponentsjs?

Question is, how can I get cssRules?

I can't see any information about getting sheet in their website. Have any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide more code? What is this['root']? What is the context?

Comment: Sure, I edited my question, so I want to inside my `<template><style>` find the rules and change it.

Comment: @Supersharp The situation is, I have create 3 divs that will append to a fragment, finally append to the shadow root. So, I needed to change the rules after appended to shadow root. Maybe not the good way, or any advise?

Comment: @Supersharp Yes, still work in chrome when I added webcomponents.js

Comment: @Supersharp You're right, I'm using <link rel="import">. And yes, I can't fetch the right one since I can't get everything inside the Object... I don't know how can I get cssRules using webcomponents.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method is different whether you use Shadow DOM or not.

A way for accessing the `sheet` inside the polyfilled Shadow DOM is to use the `setTimeout()` function in the `attachedCallback()` method, because it's only after that moment that the stylesheet becomes available.

```
prototype.attachedCallback = function ()
{
    var style = this.shadowRoot.querySelector( 'style' )

    setTimeout( function () 
    { 
        var sheet = style.sheet
        console.info( 'sheet is ok =>', sheet )
        //you can modify styles here:
        sheet.cssRules[0].style.color = 'dodgerblue'
    } )
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, but I still can't get cssRules using webcomponentjs. if I console.log, it will show the styleSheets, but if I point to it, it will undefined.

Comment: Yes, I use Shadow DOM. I'm not change the main document, I change `document.currentScript.ownerDocument`. So, I do change css style at the last step.

Comment: Thank you, need `attachedCallback()` method to get cssRules.

Comment: But do you know why it will applied the last style to all elements in safari and firefox? The cssRules has changed one by one right the way, but finally it will change all elements cssRules. (Just happened in Firefox and safari)

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Maybe you could post another question and explain it.